# Hide Scroll to Top Button for mobile

Tags: jquery

I created a Back to Top button for a website I'm building. The button fades in and out normally on bigger resolutions but I couldn't make it disappear on mobile. I finally used the jQuery remove() method for smaller screens. Is there a better way to do this? Here is my code

```
<i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up fa-3x scrollToTop"></i>


.scrollToTop{
    width:70px; 
    height:70px;    
    text-align:center; 
    position:fixed;
    bottom:50px;
    right:10px;
    color: #09C;
    display:none;
    opacity: .5;

}
.scrollToTop:active, .scrollToTop:hover  {
    color: #09C;
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor:pointer;
}


   $(document).ready(function(){
    var $scrollButton = $(".scrollToTop");
    var $screenWidth = $(window).width();
    if ($screenWidth<480) {
        $scrollButton.remove();
    } else {
        $('body').append($scrollButton);
    };
    $(window).scroll(function(){            
        if($(this).scrollTop()>500)
        {
            $scrollButton.fadeIn("slow");
        } else {
            $scrollButton.fadeOut("slow");
        };
    });
    $scrollButton.click(function(){
        $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 800);
        return false;
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in css with media tags. Just hide the button on small screens. I think around 320px wide is ok for mobile. Display:none on small screens w3c has gold documentation on media tags

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It was the first thing I tried, resolving it with a media query but for some reason it didn't wok That's why I used the remove() function to take the button out of the DOM in smaller resolutions. It feels kind of intrusive though, that's why I'm wondering whether there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You Can do it by adding some css style:

```
@media only screen and ( max-width: 767px ) {
    .scrollToTop{
        display:none !important;
    }
}
```